# Is it Ok to use '../' in relative paths?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, extjs, relative-path

I am using extjs4 to build a webapp that resides within drupal.
Many of my ajax calls are to menu items in a module within drupal.
The images my css directs to sometimes reside within my extjs folder, and sometimes in drupal.

A coworker insists that relative paths that use '../dir_a/' are bad design, and are prone to risks.

Is this correct?
Is there another way?

My folder structure:

```
- drupal
   - v2 (extjs home folder)
      - css
      - extjs
   - sites
      - mySite
          - modules
              - webApp
```

My css files contain calls like these:

```
.x-action-col-cell img.restart-test-icon {
    background-image: url(../extjs/examples/sandbox/images/gears.png);
}
```

My applications has calls like these:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: '../webapp/tests/create/',
   method: 'Post'
});
```

**Edit:** Commenters have asked for clarification.
The coworker's two main issue with this are:
1. "If the server side code will generate an address like `/a/b/c` without a trailing `/` you might have a situation where you get `/a/b/c../d`"
*True? This sounds more like a server side problem.*
2. "Have you seen anyone else using it?"
*Which in my opinion is a very poor way to decide anything.*
But I went ahead and tested some JS intensive sites (gmail, aws), using firebug and found no use of `../` in their JS or CSS.
Can anyone help me back up my claim that it's perfectly OK?

Comment: ask your coworker which risks does he refer to

Comment: Relative paths are most commonly used in CSS files whereas within actualy web pages/apps I'd suggest that absolute paths are probably more commonplace - that's certainly how I've always went about things - but each to their own.

Comment: It's OK, but I think that using relative URLs to the root is better because it's easy to make a mistake if you use `../`. For example, suppose you want to go 5 directories up but you use only four `../`.

Comment: The only risk I can think of is if you're using a server side language like PHP and allowing users to look at files on the server, without sanitizing/sandboxing the path via `fileviewer.php?file=somefile.txt`.  You don't want them reading `../../my_secret_passwords.txt`.  As far as client side goes, I can't think of any _risks_.

Comment: Your server should only serve pages that the client is allowed to access.  So whether or not your client code uses `../` is irrelevant to any security concerns.  Always assume that the client is going to modify their javascript and css if that would allow them to access things they couldn't normally access.  As far as I see it, the main difference with using relative paths is it means that your application can be moved anywhere in the website hierarchy and will still work.  That is a plus in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a. "If the server side code will generate an address like /a/b/c without a trailing / you might have a situation where you get
>   /a/b/c../d" True? This sounds more like a server side problem.

I can't think of any problem, if paths are well configured in your files.

> b. "Have you seen anyone else using it?" Which in my opinion is a very poor way to decide anything.

It is a poor way, indeed (1). I tried the first website available (stackoverflow.com), see all.css included in this page:

```
.review-diff-bar .review-diff-bar-helper {
    background: url("../Img/diff-icons/full-html-diff.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    ...
}

.openid-identifier {
    background: url("../img/openid-large.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
    ...
}
```

this is a css, but the same applies to js files.

(1) info about fallacies like this one: http://www.fallacyfiles.org/ignorant.html

Comment: Thanks mate. Good answer. How did I not think to search here?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty poor argument, it's akin to saying:

If you don't sanitize your database inputs, you can be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack, therefore, I will not use a database.

This is pretty much the same case, a matter of sanitizing your inputs.

It's highly likely whatever server side stack you're using has built in functionality (or a library) to handle these things, similar to the Path class in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w(v=vs.71)

Answer (score 1):

> If the server side code will generate an address like /a/b/c without
>   a trailing / you might have a situation where you get /a/b/c../d

This isn't how it works.  If you are at `/a/b/c` and reference `../d`, the browser requests `/a/b/d` because `c` isn't a directory, `/a/b/` is.  Now if you're just concatenating strings, I could see there being a problem (note that a lot of languages have functions for assembling paths).  That's not necessarily a *risk*, you just end up asking for the wrong file.

Now I have seen some really dumb crawlers come through my site while attempting to use relative urls combined with the `base` tag and ended up with thousands of 404s in my logs... because they didn't take into account the fact that all of my relative links are meant to be prepended with my base tag's href.  Without using the base tag, I haven't had problems (I'm not advocating either way relative vs absolute).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue for *not using* relative paths is that every move of a file that refers to other files (e.g. your css, html, and js files) would require you to change the references in this file.

Also, if you have an html sourcing a javascript that sources another javascript that sources a css file, then it is often unclear to developers what would be the relative path (it's quite common to have developers make mistakes in thie area - is it the containing HTML path or the referenced caller path?)

Moreover, as mentioned in one comment, this practice leads to using the same pattern on a server-side level which may, at some occasions, cause a slight security risk.

The main reason to *use* relative urls is that it allows you to move the entire project from one directory to another without having to change a thing. This cannot be done if you were using root-relative urls.

All in all, the decision is really personal and project dependent. I usually prefer root-relative urls, but I've had also just relative urls.

The best thing would be, by the way, to have a server-side or compile-time variable that you can use as a root, which give you both stability and flexibility, but often this is a luxury that few people have.

Comment: I've thought about your last suggestion, but in JS that means a global variable, which is never a very good thing. Also the css will be oblivious to it. So we didn't accomplish much.  
Thanks for your answer.